# sequelize: createdAt empty in findOne()

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize 5.6.1 to retrieve record from `verifLog` model on Nodejs 10.15 server:

```
hit = await VerifLog.findOne({where : {vcode: vcode_received, 
                                        cell: cell, 
                                        cell_country_code: cell_country_code, 
                                        device_id: device_id, 
                                        redeemed: false}});
```

But the `createdAt` is empty in `hit` even though there is a valid value (`2019-04-27 23:10:15.827-07`) in the table for createdAt:

```
hit is :  veriflog {
  dataValues:
   { id: 31,
     cell: '6303623200',
     cell_country_code: '1',
     vcode: '90282',
     device_id: '8c9c25711c7d0262',
     redeemed: false,
     user_id: '20',
     createdAt: 2019-04-28T06:10:15.827Z },
  _previousDataValues:
   { id: 31,
     cell: '6303623200',
     cell_country_code: '1',
     vcode: '90282',
     device_id: '8c9c25711c7d0262',
     redeemed: false,
     user_id: '20',
     createdAt: 2019-04-28T06:10:15.827Z },
  _changed: {},
.......
```

Here is the VerifLog model:

```
const VerifLog = db.define('veriflog', {
    /* id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
         primaryKey:true,
         autoIncrement: true,
         min: 1}, */
    cell: Sql.STRING,
    cell_country_code: Sql.STRING,
    vcode: Sql.STRING,
    device_id: Sql.STRING,
    redeemed: {
        type: Sql.BOOLEAN,
        default: false
    },
    user_id: Sql.INTEGER,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    updatedAt: false,
    indexes: [
        {
            fields: ['cell_country_code', 'cell'],
        },
        {
            fields: ["device_id"],
        },
        {
            fields: ["redeemed"],
        },
        {
            fields: ['user_id'],
        },
    ],
});
```

I have no clue why (only) `createdAt` is returned empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `createdAt` and `updatedAt` in your model. My guess is that though the data is available in the record, because you haven't defined the fields in your model attributes sequelize does not define getters for `createdAt` and `updatedAt`.